# What do the characters - 'pub' mean in std::streambuf::pubsetbuf() method?

Tags: c++

I know this method is used to set a buffer for `std::streambuf`, I just don't understand the `pub` part means in `std::streambuf::pubseekoff`

Comment: I would says `public`, as there is a `protected` `virtual` `seekoff`.

Comment: "Pub" as in "public". As opposed to [the protected `setbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf).

Answer (score 6):

The `pub` is for `public`.  `std::streambuf::pubseekoff` is the public face of the protected virtual function `seekoff`.

Since you cannot overload a function based on it being virtual, one of the functions had to be given a different name.